# How to check if nested hash attributes are empty

Tags: ruby

I have a Hash

```
person_params = {"firstname"=>"",
     "lastname"=>"tom123",
     "addresses_attributes"=>
      {"0"=>
        {"address_type"=>"main",
         "catalog_delivery"=>"0",
         "street"=>"tomstr",
         "city"=>"tomcity"
        }
      }
    }
```

With `person_params[:addresses_attributes]`, I get:

```
# => {"0"=>{"address_type"=>"main", "catalog_delivery"=>"0", "street"=>"tomstr", "zip"=>"", "lockbox"=>"", "city"=>"tomcity", "country"=>""}}
```

1) How can I get a new hash without the leading `0`?

```
desired_hash = {"address_type"=>"main", "catalog_delivery"=>"0", "street"=>"tomstr", "zip"=>"", "lockbox"=>"", "city"=>"tomcity", "country"=>""}
```

2) How can I check whether the attributes in the new hash are empty?

Comment: i found a solution for my first question: person_params[:addresses_attributes].first.last  anyway is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer 1:

```
person_params[:addresses_attributes]['0']
```

Answer 2:

```
hash = person_params[:addresses_attributes]['0']
hash.empty?
```

Comment: You might have explained why #1 works--many would have--but I think that would have made the answer less useful to the asker and other readers who are new to Ruby. If a reader doesn't understand that immediately, they will be able to figure it out,  and by doing so will have burned it into their brain.

Answer (score 1):

This looks just like a params hash from Rails =D.  Anyway, it seems that your addresses_attributes contains some nested attributes.  This means that what you have in practice is more of an array of hashes than a single hash, and that's what you see right? Instead of it being an actually Ruby Array, it is a hash with the index as a string.

So how do you get the address attributes? Well if you only want to get the first address, here are some ways to do that:

```
person_params[:addresses_attributes].values.first

# OR

person_params[:addresses_attributes]["0"]
```

In the first case, we will just take the values from the addreses_attributes hash, which gives us an Array from which we can take the first item. If there are no values in addresses_attributes, then we will get `nil`.

In the second case, we will just ask for the hash value with the key "0". If there are no values in addresses_attributes, we will get `nil` with this method also. (You might want to avoid using the second case, if you are not confident that the addresses_attributes hash will always be indexed from "0" and incremented by "1")